# Play video from url

Tags: android, rss, video-streaming

I know that android support some video [formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

I am doing an application to parse video from news rss feed and play the same.
I have seen many tutorial to download video or play that video. But, all for android supported format.

I have parsed and then get this [video url](http://video.foxnews.com/assets/video-player.swf?video_id=2501811652001&d=video.foxnews.com&auto_play=true) from [channel](http://feeds.foxnews.com/~r/foxnews/video/~3/UfrFsRXYGss/) of [this news rss feed](http://feeds.foxnews.com/foxnews/video).

My questions are:

1. is [this](http://video.foxnews.com/assets/video-player.swf?video_id=2501811652001&d=video.foxnews.com&auto_play=true) correct video url?
   or is any other url will be in [this channel](http://feeds.foxnews.com/~r/foxnews/video/~3/UfrFsRXYGss/)? If so, what is that?
2. I know that this [url](http://video.foxnews.com/assets/video-player.swf?video_id=2501811652001&d=video.foxnews.com&auto_play=true) is not in downloading format. But i want to play this using player or download it on sdcard. How to achieve this?
3. Is there any way to download video using video_id of that [url](http://video.foxnews.com/assets/video-player.swf?video_id=2501811652001&d=video.foxnews.com&auto_play=true)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the url u mentioned above : is that static or the news or video is changing dynamically in this same url ?

Comment: I don't know about that. But each channel of news contains unique url. I think it will be static

Comment: if its static video or news why dont you use webview and play it ,instead of caching the video.

Comment: I want to play it in my customized media controller. For that, I want to download it on SDCard.

Comment: Their videos seem tied with their swf player. I dont think you can download their videos and then play, probably because they dont want you to. You could try this  `http://video.foxnews.com/assets/video-player.swf?video_id=2501811652001` but I doubt it'll work mainly because they dont want you to download their videos and play them but play it off their own server with their own video player. Check their policies/rss notes and see if they have instructions.Plus you will probably have to convert it to another fmt after download, so its probably best if you just call it and let their player play

Comment: @Slartibartfast If i want to play with their player itself, what will i do?

Comment: Create a webview, and just open the url you've pasted - http://video.foxnews.com/assets/video-player.swf?video_id=2501811652001&d=video.foxnews.com&auto_play=true

Comment: I couldn't control this video using my customized media controller right???

Comment: Nope. You'll just reuse their controls. I dont think they have exposed only their videos through the url for download. Like I said you could try playing `http://video.foxnews.com/assets/video-player.swf?video_id=2501811652001` in your media controller. If you cant it probably just means they havent exposed their videos for download and you can just play it through their player

Answer (score 0):

To play a video in VideoView

```
   String SrcPath = "path to the link.fileformat";


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
   myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
   myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
   myVideoView.requestFocus();
   myVideoView.start();
   }
```

To download a file from a specified URL plz refer to the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878241/android-download-file-code-not-working)

And dont forget to put the permission in Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code to download a file

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(provide any URL);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/download/";
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "PATH: " + PATH);
        File file = new File(PATH);
        file.mkdirs();

        String fileName = "filename.swf";


        File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {

            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);

        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();

        // }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error: " + e);


    }
```

Comment: yes it will not play as android apps don't play swf videos. you need to convert it to MP4 format